# Cumilative Total for end of each month

Tags: excel, powerbi, pivot, dax, ssas

I am new to dax .
I am trying to get the cumulative sales total for end of each month.

I have created a measure that calculates total sales called "MeasureTotalSum"
MeasureTotalSum = Sum(FactSales[SaleAmount])

Then  I have used that below,

Sales:=CALCULATE (
[MeasureSalesSum],
FILTER (
ALL ( DimDate[Datekey] ),
DimDate[Datekey] <= MAX ( ( DimDate[Datekey] ) )
)
)

But i am not able to get sum of MeasureTotalSum at the end of each month.(I need sum of MeasureTotalSum  for last day of every month )

Example : value @ Jan31 + Feb28 +March31 + Jume30 ......Dec31 for every year.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi - Miguel  I have updated the post. Thanks for checking.